# How to check if a table contains some key inside __index?

Tags: lua

I want to optimize a Fibonacci function but using table index, and memoization seems a good method (iteration is as good)... However, soon I ran into a problem: I can't decide whether a key is in a table. How can I do that?

```
local fib = {}

function fib_index(t, k)
   if k == 0 or k == 1 then
      t[k] = k
   else
      t[k] = t[k-1] + t[k-2]
   end
   return t[k]
end
setmetatable(fib, {__index = fib_index})
```

Comment: `rawget(fib, k)`

Comment: See also https://github.com/brimworks/lua/blob/master/test/fib.lua

Comment: Why do you need to test that? The index metamethod is only called when the table does not contain the key. Your code works fine. I'd put the base case directly in the definition of the table: `fib = {[0]=0, [1]=1}`. This greatly simplifies `fib_index`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will run just fine in it's current state. The reason behind that is that already strored values have highter priority than `__index` metamethod, so if value does exist, it's returned immideately. There are few optimisations which can make your code look better:

```
local fib = setmetatable({1, 1}, {__index = function(t,k)
    assert(k > 0, 'Invalid fib index') -- Most basic check
    local res = t[k-1] + t[k-2]
    t[k] = res
    return res
end})
```

Here I remove function declaration at all (if you want to reuse it, consider making your function local with `local function` instead of `function`) and made code easier by adding inital values directly into table declaration (no index `0` to keep it lua way, also no zero in results) and utilizing the fact that `setmetatable` return originally passed table. You can remove `assert` if you want to, but it's probably good idea to see meaningful error message instead of "stack overflow".

And if you *really* wanna check does value exist in table (this code *does not* require this), use `rawget`:

```
rawget(fib, 10) == nil
```

will tell you is `10` already calculated and cached.